# ApplicationExit event not being raised

Tags: c#, windows, msdn

I'm trying to save some data when the program is forced to exit.

For example if the PC shuts down or it gets closed by the Task Manager.

It's not a console or a Winforms application. It's just a background process without a user interface.

```
namespace Test
{
    class Test
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(OnProcessExit);
            //some stuff to do here
        }

        static void OnProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //saving all the important data
            Console.WriteLine("Im out of here!");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I tried. I didn't got any errors, but my handler isn't called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least two issues here.

The `Application.ApplicationExit` event is raised only when you've called `Application.Run()` and the `Run()` method is about to return (e.g. you've called `Application.Exit()` or `Application.ExitThread()`, or closed the last/main window, etc.). In a non-GUI program where you've never called `Application.Run()`, the `Application` object doesn't have a chance to raise the event.

Forcefully terminating a process can prevent *any* more code from executing, including event handlers. For a non-GUI process, a more appropriate event to handle would be `AppDomain.ProcessExit`. But even this event might not be raised, if you terminate your process forcefully.

So, try the `AppDomain.ProcessExit` event. But be aware that depending on how the process is terminated, even that might not be raised.

If you need more specific help than that, provide a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what you've tried, reproduces whatever problem you're having, and explain in precise and *specific* details what exact behavior the code has now and what you want instead.

Additional reading:
[How to run code before program exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2555292)
[C# Windows Program Exit Request (Detect Application.Exit) No Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24100393)
[How to detect when application terminates?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1372123)

None of these related posts really seem to cover adequately the "forceful termination" scenario and so aren't technically exact duplicates of your question, but they do provide a variety of good discussion on techniques to detect your own process exiting.

Answer (score 0):

If you or anyone of you who visits here are working on Form then this might help.

This is what worked for me:

```
public Form1{
  //some code...
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(OnProcessExit);

}
public void OnProcessExit(object sender,EventArgs e){
   MyDataLoggerMethod("Monitoring ended.");
}
```